# Check if multiline textbox has only newline characters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using .Net 2.0 how can i check if a multi line text box has only newline characters?

No text at all, but only \n, \r, etc..?

Comment: Replace all `\n` etc with "", and see if anything is left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(@"^[\r\n]+$", text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) method.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
{

}
```

Here is the source of IsNullOrWhiteSpace -

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return true;
    for (int index = 0; index < value.Length; ++index)
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(value[index]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm using .net 2.0. And that function is only available on .net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing `Environment.NewLine` with nothing?

For example,

```
Dim tbLen as Integer = tb.Text.Length() 'returns 2 for 1 return character

Dim tbLenFiltered As Integer = tb.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty).Length() 'returns 0 for 1 return character
```